# npm start command is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have tried running it using command line and in webstorm.
Earlier it was running smoothly but now it has stopped working.
I am not able to figure out what the error is?
If i look at line 13 it says failed to execute start script.
How can i rectify this error?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run-script',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.8.3
3 info using node@v4.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle WebDev@0.0.0~prestart: WebDev@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle WebDev@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle WebDev@0.0.0~start: WebDev@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle WebDev@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle WebDev@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/vardaan/Projects_Github/WebDev/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
10 verbose lifecycle WebDev@0.0.0~start: CWD: /home/vardaan/Projects_Github/WebDev
11 silly lifecycle WebDev@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node ./bin/www' ]
12 silly lifecycle WebDev@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle WebDev@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: WebDev@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:239:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
15 verbose pkgid WebDev@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/vardaan/Projects_Github/WebDev
17 error Linux 3.19.0-58-generic
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "run-script" "start"
19 error node v4.4.0
20 error npm  v3.8.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error WebDev@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the WebDev@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the WebDev package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node ./bin/www
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs WebDev
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls WebDev
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The ./bin/www script is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('WebDev:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: Can you include what your `npm start` script actually is? Or even better, includes your `prestart`, `start` and `poststart` scripts.

Comment: do you mean package.json? I am not sure where to find these scripts.Can you please help me out.

Comment: Yes, inside your `package.json` the `scripts` property.

Comment: `"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }`

Comment: only start property is present.